# Unusual CSS Transition behaviour. Can you disable specific parameters?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a transition on elements of a table in order to provide a pretty cool border effect, this all works fine.

The problem I'm getting is that occasionally (not every time) on page refresh each individual box will transition in as if all of the variables are blank and will resize from (presumably) height 0 width 0 to height 250 and width 250. It looks incredibly ugly and kinda ruins the whole effect of the site.

My presumption is that, for whatever reason, the transition all catch is misinterpreting some variables as being null or zero, then transitioning from that to 250. However I can't test this as, as far as I know, you cannot make an exception for width and height.

I've tried manually setting a transition for the six important parameters (outline, outline-offset, color, background-image, background-position, background-size) but this simply results in the transition not working correctly, the background image simply snaps on and off with no transitions at all... so something must be going on.

Here is the code;

```
#portfolio-table td{
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
min-width: 250px;
min-height: 250px;

box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.35);

outline: 3px solid black;
outline-offset: -3px;

color: transparent !important; /* Makes text invisible until hover */

background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;

text-align: center;

transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    }

#portfolio-table td:hover{
outline: 10px solid white;
outline-offset: -10px;

color: black !important; /* Makes text visible */

box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.35);

background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg) !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;

cursor: pointer;

transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

It might be important to note that background-image is being set by CSS per-cell. Heres the code for that;

```
#portfolio-table #project1{
background-image: url(../images/project7.jpg);
     }
```

There is a lot of repetition in the hover (for example the no-repeat and background-size) in an attempt to prevent this unusual behaviour.

As you can see a min-size is set for both width and height, but it still transitions in as if it was 0.

[This](http://www.alecvickers.co.uk/) is a link to a live example; if you spam refresh you should notice the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
```

I have had this problem before and i solved it with changing the .35 to 0.35

Comment: No I'm afraid that's not it. The problem continues exactly as before.

Comment: I made a quick test on my own domain, but i don't see anything strange with your script. When i check your site, and i refresh alot of time, i don't see anything strange either. I assume you want the background to stay when you mouse over? Else then that looks working?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. 

The effect is supposed to be the 'cover' for the project displayed, then on mouseover it changes to the 'default' background, the same grid as the rest of the site, with the text and "view project" link.

However what it does on mine is, occasionally, when you refresh it will strangely resize the projects in an extremely unappealing way. They'll stretch from some unknown size into the 250x250 they ultimately arrive at.

Comment: Oh I should also mention that I tried completely removing the shadows, same problem persists. It's definitely transforming something it shouldn't be at random.

Comment: I see, when i try it in Firefox it works, but in Chrome it does this indeed. I shall take a look for you if you cannot find out urself

Comment: Thanks, but vals has swooped in to the rescue it seems. Although, to be fair, it is more of a work around than a diagnosis of the original problem... turns out just listing them individually is the best way to avoid that behaviour. It still actually draws a phantom box shadow if you spam refresh as before which I think is a symptom of the original problem - but it's more the acceptable, as the resizing was really bad. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Good. Then this question is solved ;) i will take a look anyways if i can find the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the transition to

```
#portfolio-table td{

    ... 
transition: outline, outline-offset, color, box-shadow, background-image 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

and it works ok for me.

Comment: Thanks, that almost fixed it. I can't recreate the problems I was having by doing each one individually, but this version almost does it. However I had to add the time and transition method to each individual variable, otherwise it only does the last one. Not sure if this is local to whatever browser you're using or not? I'm using Chrome primarily. Thanks!